# Switch to Steve-Type skin (4 wide arms) while offline

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play on offline Minecraft and I'm stuck with the Alex skin for 1.8. I have a custom resource pack that changes my skin but it still has the small arms. I was wondering if there was any way in game offline that I could get the 4 pixel wide arms instead of the 3 pixel wide arms. I'm playing in 1.8.8.

Comment: There is a way to do this without any mods or texture packs, getting onto it now.

Comment: I'm assuming your playing it the "hacked" way since you can't change your skin? :P

Answer (score 2):

This, unfortunately, cannot be changed *in-game* as far as Vanilla Minecraft goes. To change from Steve or Alex, you will instead have to go on the Minecraft website, log in, and enter the [Profile](https://minecraft.net/profile) page. From there, **you can choose to have a skin that fits Steve** (though if you don't want a skin, all you need is to switch to Steve and Save).

Comment: Is there anything outside of vanilla Minecraft that can change this? Mods plugins etc.

Comment: @KingDarren7203 I think there was something, but I'm unsure if it's been updated yet. It was a LiteLoader mod of sorts, but I can't remember where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE! THIS ANSWER IS OUTDATED. IT NO LONGER FITS THE QUESTION**

There IS a way!

You can make a resource pack that changes the look of Alex (or Steve)!

download the recource pack here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/h0rw97kwaa12u0m/alexChange.zip

unzip the file, and navigate to the folder then to assets->minecraft->textures->entity

in this folder, paste your skin file. if it an Alex skin, name it "alex.png". if it Steve, name it "steve.png".

Move the entire resource pack to your recource packs folder in your minecraft directory.

remember that if you go on a multiplayer server, all players with no skin will show up as your skin, so remember to switch resource packs!

Comment: Is there a way to have it use Steve as the model and not Alex?

Comment: I dont think so, but there might be a steve skin for the alex model

Comment: @KingDarren7203 After looking thru the files of minecraft, i could not find the model for alex. Therefore i think there is no way to change the skin type offline without mods.